# React - state contains array of objects. setState with conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting an error that 'exampleState' is not iterable, but why?

Say that I have a state variable which holds a simple array of objects

```
const [exampleState, setExampleState] = useState([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mary'
    }
])
```

I want to change the values of these objects conditionally. I thought a loop with a conditional inside would be an easy way to do this. I tried the following...

```
for (let item of exampleState) {
    if (item.name === 'John') {
        setExampleState({...exampleState, name: 'Michael'})
    }
}
```

but I get the following error: 'TypeError' exampleState is not iterable

How should I do this instead?

Comment: You should be able to do `for ... in` instead of `for ... of` here I think and the rest should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the usual way to go about this, in general, is to update the state the least times you need to. Secondly, you are trying to update the value of the state with an object, whereas it is a list when it's initialized. This can be achieved using a single update:

```
setExampleState(...exampleState.map((user) => {
  if (user.name === 'John') {
    user.name = 'Michael';
  }
  return user;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` for that like this

```
setExampleState(state => state.map(s => s.name === 'John'?{...s, name:'Michael' }: s))
```

if you set the state in a loop you always overwriting your array with a single element

Answer (score 0):

You should check [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) library, it is awesome for operating immutable data structures like that.